# What is the correct way of translating with onclicks with react-spring

Tags: react-spring

```
    const props = useSpring({
    transform: toggle ? "translateX(-200px)" : "translateX(0)",
    opacity: toggle ? 1 : 0
});
```

I currently have a div with above styles and opacity works fine with the onclicks, but i'm having trouble with translation. 
Basically i want to animate sort of a slide out div. What would be the correct way of going about it?

Comment: i just realized that "translate(0)" needs the 'px' so "translate(0px)" is the fix.